# Acting with a matrix on each line of a table, where each line is treated as a separate vector

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to create a table containing rows of the components of randomly generated unit vectors in 3D. I do this by ResourceFunction["RandomUnitVector"][3, 4] // TableForm. Then I want to multiply the components of each vector by one and the same factor called "a". Next I want to add another entry in the table as a first component m, which is the same on each row. This should leave me with a table with four columns, the first element of each row to be m, so that each line represents a 4D vector. Finally, I would like to act on each line (each 4D vector) with a pre-defined matrix and to obtain a table with the final vectors. Is that possible to be done in Mathematica? I hope I have explained that problem clearly, but if not I would be happy to answer any questions.

Function[x, a x] /@ T Unfortunately, I cannot add another column and then treat each line as a vector, on which to act with a matrix.

Comment: Yes; you can do this. But it is unclear what exactly you are trying to do. Show the code for your attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look at the output of `v=Map[Prepend[#,m]&,a*ResourceFunction["RandomUnitVector"][3,4]]`